# Java Expression Evaluation Error

Tags: java, expression, evaluation

I'm trying to find a ratio between a song's current position and its total playing time. 
`long pTime = player.getCurrentBufferedTimeMcsec();`
`long pos = player.getCurrentPosition();`
`return (int)(pos/pTime * 1000000l);`

The return expression is evaluated as zero. How can i fix this? I'm guessing it's a mixture of what type I use and concatenation, right?

Thanks!

*Edit* I already checked and the "player.get" calls return values, but once divided yield a decimal (like 0.06) before it is multiplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
pos/pTime
```

Both operands are `long`, so the result with be `long`, which will truncate any fractional part. If `pTime` is greater than `pos`, the result of the division (and of course the final result) will be zero.

Change the code to allow a floating point result by casting one of the operands to a floating point type:

```
return (int)((double)pos/pTime * 1000000l);
```

When one of the operands is `double`, the result will be `double`.

---

Additional tip: Don't use lowercase `l` for `long` constants - it looks like a `1`. Use uppercase `1000000L`, or in this case drop the `L` altogether as it's unnecessary, because `1000000` is a valid `int`, which will be safely promoted to `long` or `double` anyway:

```
    return (int)((double)pos/pTime * 1000000);
```

Comment: Or, to avoid floating point entirely: `1000000l * pos/pTime`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry i thaught i tried this but it was in the eclipse expresions window... dont know what happened there, but thanks all the same, and sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Cast either `pos` or `pTime` to `double`. You are getting integral truncation on division.